# how to set precision of DS18B20 via w1-therm?

Tags: gpio, driver, ds18b20

According to the documentation for w1-therm:

> Writing a value between 9 and 12 to the sysfs w1_slave file will change the
>   precision of the sensor for the next readings. This value is in (volatile)
>   SRAM, so it is reset when the sensor gets power-cycled.
>
> To store the current precision configuration into EEPROM, the value 0
>   has to be written to the sysfs w1_slave file. Since the EEPROM has a limited
>   amount of writes (>50k), this command should be used wisely.

I can read the w1_slave file(s) easily enough:

```
pi@xenon:~$ cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28*/w1_slave
a0 01 80 80 1f ff 80 80 f5 : crc=f5 YES
a0 01 80 80 1f ff 80 80 f5 t=26000
```

But I haven't yet figured out how to write them:

```
pi@xenon:~$ sudo echo 12 >/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0315549b98ff/w1_slave 
-bash: /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0315549b98ff/w1_slave: Permission denied
```

Any insight into how to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions problem is because the redirection (>) is done before sudo takes effect.

Try the following invocation.

`sudo sh -c "echo 12 >/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0315549b98ff/w1_slave"`

This should run the shell with sudo and then issue the command.

Comment: Thanks! And I subsequently learned that writing a zero tells the driver to write it into the device's EEPROM, thereby making it permanent.